# Sometimes, html pages generated with jstl don't render completely

Tags: jstl

I am working with spring to make a web application. For UI, I use jstl. But when I run the app on tomee, my page doesn't show up correctly. I have looked at the html source code of the page in my browser and it's not complete. It seems that jstl doesn't generate all the page. What can be the reason of that ?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to solve this problem.

Add <%@ page buffer="128kb" autoFlush="false" %> at the beginning of your jsp file.